# If two planes are parallel, then is any line in one plane parallel to the second plane?

Tags: geometry, soft-question

*Question*

If two planes are parallel, then is it true that any line in one plane is parallel to the second plane?

I need this to solve a more complex problem.

Hope one of you can tell me if this is right it wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

A line is parallel to a plane if the direction vector of the line is perpendicular to the normal vector of the plane. If two planes are parallel, they have parallel normal vectors. Any line in one plane will by definition be perpendicular to the normal vector of *that* plane, and by extension also to the normal vector of the other plane.